# Replace for Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I've noticed that Hibernate's [Entity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Entity.html) is Deprecated. What shall I use to achieve simillar effect without having deprecated annotations in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JPA annotations. They are in the javax.persistence package. `javax.persistence.Entity`